# Javascript: how to check if a string ends with 2 letters followed by an integer?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check if a string ends with `ab` followed by an integer.

Given any string `s`, how can I first check if it ends with `ab1` or `ab2` or a`b3`, and if so, return `ab1` or `ab2` or `ab3`.

For example, for string `sdfsadfsab2`, I want to return `ab2`.
For string `asdfase` I want to return empty string.

Is there any regular expression in javascript or jquery can do this? thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Regular expressions are a *language* feature and therefore have nothing to do with jQuery.

Comment: does 'an integer' include more than one digit?  That is, should 'sdgab345' return 'ab345'?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The regex you're after could well be:

```
/ab[0-9]$/
```

If you want a tester function, that function could look something like this:

```
function testABInt(string)
{
    var match = string.match(/ab[0-9]$/);
    return match ? match[0] : '';
}
```

This only matches the end of a string if `ab` are lower-case chars, and if there is only **one** int at the end, to match case-insensitive, add the `i` flag, and/or add a `+` to match all trailing digits:

```
/ab[0-9]+$/i
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `replace`:

```
str.replace(/.*(ab\d+)$/, "$1");
```

Another way using `match`:

```
(str.match(/ab\d+$/) || [""]).pop();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var regex = /([a-zA-Z]{2}[0-9])$/;
var str = "sdfsadfsab2";
console.log(str.match(regex)[0]); //outputs "ab2"
```

#### Explanation of regex:

- `[a-zA-Z]` - a collection of the letters from a-z in lower and upper case
- `{2}` - meaning "repeated exactly 2 times"
- `[0-9]` - a collection of the digits from 0 to 9
- `$` - meaning "end of the string"

Answer (score 1):

Use `$` to match the end of the string:

```
'foo2'.match(/[a-z]{2}\d$/);
```

Comment: This also matches any other two lower-case letters e.g. "no1". That wasn't asked!

Comment: @MartinM.: Well, I interpreted `ab` as being `[a-z]{2}`, not *literally* the characters `ab`.